# Is it possible to format a displayed data in Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel-5, voyager

I'm new at [Voyager](https://voyager.readme.io/docs) and I wanted to to format some numbers to a currency format. Normally, I'd do it like

`//In a blade file
{{ $number_format($product->price, 0, ',', '.') }}`

If I want to format the displayed data in a BREAD view, how should be my JSON string to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Eloquent accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

In your instance, this might look like:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Product extends Model
    {
        /**
         * Get the product's price.
         *
         * @param  string  $value
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPriceAttribute($value)
        {
            return number_format($value, 0, ',', '.');
        }
    }
```